# Add Colors In Magento2 Admin Catalog Product Grid

Tags: grid, product, magento2, catalog

Using Magento 2.2, Admin Grid. I want to add style to the Status column in the Catalog product.

Answer (score 0):

Please copy those files and move them to the your theme.
add this code in below file

```
 attr="style: getColorStyle($row())"
```

vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/web/templates/grid/listing.html

```
 <tr class="data-row" repeat="foreach: rows, item: '$row'" css="'_odd-row': $index % 2" attr="style: getColorStyle($row())">
  <td outerfasteach="data: getVisible(), as: '$col'" css="getFieldClass($row())" click="getFieldHandler($row())" template="getBody()"/>
 </tr>
```

and add this function in below file

```
 getColorStyle: function(row)
 {
  /*
   var jsonData = JSON.stringify(row);
   console.log(jsonData);
  */
  if(row['status'] == '1'){
   styles =  'background: #fefafa';
  }else{
   styles =  'background: #6a0dad';
  }
  return styles;
 }
```

vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/web/js/grid/listing.js